# How can I compile a study material of a course in this case?

Tags: books, lecture-notes

Last year I was appointed to lecture a Data Structures course in a university in my hometown. The material for making my notes were based on several books, articles and also some material from Coursera in the cases that I needed to simplify some material or needed some exercises.

The notes included a final set of references at which the student could look after, like books, articles or urls of some online courses that I found interesting and from where I based my lecture notes.

This year the Dean of my Faculty has told me to convert all that study material into a book that could serve as a guide for the new students. The question that I have is if this would be really necessary? I mean it is not enough that the students could check up the material on this course based on the primary authors in which I based my set of notes? I bet to have a look in the original source would be far way better for the student than just considering the set of notes that I made.

What suggestions do you have to convert this study material into a small book for the students who would take this course?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are obliged to prepare what some may recall as a *minimum learning material*. It is what a student might need to get the a broad knowledge of the subject before s/he is to delve into the details.

If you are concerned that the original source ought to be referred due to its importance, then you might include this sentence...

> The provided study material is by no means a complete replacement to the prescribed textbooks/sources on the subject.

...somewhere in the beginning of the material, such as the preface section. It what I usually do when compiling such notes.